# Jxl.jar in android

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I don't know how to add jxl.jar in android studio 
I tried to pasts jxl.jar in lib project and using project structure 
then tried to start to create `WorkBook` obj 
but not working.

what I missed?

Comment: did you try this gradle dependencies {
    compile 'com.hynnet:jxl:2.6.12.1'
}???

Answer (score 7):

If you use gradle (Android Studio), then add in dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'net.sourceforge.jexcelapi:jxl:2.6.12'
}
```

Answer (score 2):

- Paste your `jxl.jar` into the libs folder
- Right click it and select 'Add as library'
- Make sure that `compile files('libs/jxl.jar')` is in your
  build.gradle file (or compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
  if you are using many jar files) if it still not there then you can try to add it manually by adding this `compile files('libs/jxl.jar')` inside dependancies
- Synch your project